# What is the Shadowing attribute that the VS uses when it generates unit tests?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

When i generated unit tests the Visual studio added some fictive class that mocks my class and added the "Shadowing" attribute.
What does it do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did some research and found [this](http://www.davidgiard.com/2010/02/09/UnitTestingPrivateMethods.aspx). Apparantly, the `[Shadowing]` attribute is used by `MSTest` when it creates an accessor class that allows you to call a private method on a class as if it were public.

So when you're unit testing a private method of a target class, that private method will be available to you via the accessor wrapper class for the target class.