# Creating a List of Accessors throws an ArgumentException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, runtimeexception

I get a very odd Error when creating a List of Accessors.
I have a class `Component` with a private List of `Component`s. Since I want to test some of the classes behaviour regarding this list I use an Accessor of the `Component`-class. Also I have some dependencies in the constructor of the class I want to avoid. Therefore I manually instantiate the list in a `TestInitialize()`-Method

The TestInitialize()-Code looks like this:

```cs
private string _testIdentifier = "TestComponent";
private int _testConsist = 1;

private Component_Accessor _target;

[TestInitialize()]
    public void MyTestInitialize()
    {
        _target = new Component_Accessor();
        _target.Identifier = new ComponentIdentifier(_testIdentifier, _testConsist);
        _target._inputComponents = new List<Component_Accessor>();
        _target._outputComponents = new List<Component_Accessor>();
    }
```

The Accessor-Code looks like this:

```cs
[Shadowing("_inputComponents")]  
public List<Component_Accessor> _inputComponents { get; set; }
```

This compiles just fine but I get a RunTimeException:

> The Object of the type "System.Collections.Generic.List'1[DT5_Training_Simulator.Model.Components.Component_Accessor]" can not be converted to the type "System.Collections.Generic.List'1[DT5_Training_Simulator.Model.Components.Component]"

Actually I'm quite at a loss here. Could anybody please tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Your code doesn't match your description - you're creating a new `Component_Accessor`, not a new `Component`. Are you using dynamic typing at all? If you could post a more complete section of code, that would really help.

Comment: can you provide more code showing the use of `Component` class also. probably the exception isnot becaused of provided code.

Comment: is dont know what your ShadowingAttribute really does but MSDN says: "Do not use this class" --> possibly you shouldnt?

Comment: I provided the complete initialization code. Also when I debugged the code, the Exception was raised in line 11 of the excerpt (the part with `_target._inputComponents = new List<Component_Accessor>();`)

Comment: I'd suggest a clean in visual studio. Also what does that Shadowing annotation do? I can't find anything about it.

Comment: I cleaned and rebuild the whole project several times. And Shadowing provides me (in this case) with a mean to access private properties of a class. A good and short description can be found here: [StackOverflow Shadowing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673779/what-is-shadowing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not use `Shadowing` attribute with public members, because it confuses the tester. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443755/what-is-the-shadowing-attribute-that-the-vs-uses-when-it-generates-unit-tests), `Shadowing` is used to test private properties and methods as if they were public. Your property is already public, so you need to remove `Shadowing` from its declaration.